# facebook4j how to getPictureURL size 480x480?

Tags: java, facebook

From API graph it is possible to get profile picture of 480x480 and also 640x640, it is possible to do the same thing with facebook4j?

the  enum PictureSize.large  is  200x200 ...

Comment: Well, I think it is NOT implemented yet... I submitted a new feature to facebook4j team in GitHub    [https://github.com/roundrop/facebook4j/pull/72]

Comment: Does anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! I downloaded the branch from Github and I solved; when will the merge of the project for use with maven?

Comment: This feature was included in facebook4j v. 2.2.1 of 31 december 2014